# SFINAE-based Operator Overloading across Namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm attempting to use an approach which allows for automatic enabling of bitmask operators for strongly typed enum classes. See below header and cpp of an example.

https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/files/bitmask_operators.hpp
https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/files/testbitmask.cpp

The approach in testbitmask.cpp works when everything is in the same namespace, however I would like to separate the SFINAE code in a different namespace from the usage by other classes (see below or https://wandbox.org/permlink/05xXaViZT3MVyiBl).

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace ONE {
    template<typename E>
    struct enable_bitmask_operators{
        static const bool enable=false;
    };

    template<typename E>
    inline typename std::enable_if<enable_bitmask_operators<E>::enable,E>::type
    operator|(E lhs,E rhs){
        typedef typename std::underlying_type<E>::type underlying;
        return static_cast<E>(
            static_cast<underlying>(lhs) | static_cast<underlying>(rhs));
    }
}

namespace TWO {
    enum class A{ x=1, y=2};
}

namespace ONE {
    template<>
    struct enable_bitmask_operators<TWO::A>{
        static const bool enable=true;
    };
}

int main(){
    TWO::A a1 = TWO::A::x | TWO::A::y;
}
```

This has the effect of not being able to find the overloaded operator in main. Explicitly calling the function works (`TWO::A a1 = ONE::operator|(TWO::A::x , TWO::A::y);`), but of course is not the desired functionality.

If we move the specialization into `namespace ONE`, the compiler throws an `error: declaration of 'struct ONE::enable_bitmask_operators<TWO::A>' in namespace 'TWO' which does not enclose 'ONE'`. I'm wondering if the desired approach is possible in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function cannot be found by ADL, you might add some `using` to allow to use it:

```
using ONE::operator|;
TWO::A a1 = TWO::A::x | TWO::A::y;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/051ded5bb68daaa4)

`using namespace ONE;` might be an alternative too.

Comment: I suppose this is acceptable - would prefer not to have `using` required in every cpp that uses the enum, and ideally would prefer not to have `using ONE::operator|` in the header as it is pretty generic. I can live with wrapping the enum class in another namespace and using it inside that instead. Will wait another day in case there are any other approaches, though I believe there is not.

Comment: It is similar to [`operator ""s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)' usage for `std`.